# The pupils of my rigged model don't move with the Eyes

Tags: rigging

I have been 3D modeling a character for a VR game. But after I made it and then imported it to Unreal I realized that the rigging dosen't work as expected and the pupils weren't moving even though I parented it and I did the automatic weights and even joined it with the character as one mesh.

[image: normal]

[image: wireframe]

[image: whack]

Comment: select them in Edit mode and assign them to the group they are supposed to be part of, in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, the group must have the same name as the head bone

Comment: Alright so I did that then the pupils which are 3 cylinders that are just rotated split up really weird but I just deleted it and remodeled it in the eyeballs instead of making a completely new object and joining or parenting the pupils to the head bone, or head, or eyeball. But thanks anyways for answering my question!